# Connect to wired network in Lenovo Vibe K5 using USB to Ethernet Adapter via OTG

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, hardware, internet, usb-on-the-go

It is possible to connect to the Internet through a wired connection in my smartphone Lenovo Vibe K5? I've bought a USB to Ethernet Adapter, model HB-T80, to use in my Lenovo Vibe K5 smartphone with OTG adapter, to have a wired RJ45 connection. But it does not recognizes the network card.

Is Vibe k5 with Android 6.0 Marshmallow compatible with USB to Ethernet OTG Adapters (smartphone is OTG compatible) ? Is it necessary to install some drivers, or flash some kernel?

Comment: The device itself seem to support OTG but may be not USB-to-Ethernet adapters. A custom kernel may enable such devices, however we are talking about an Android 6 device. In your case I would install a complete custom ROM instead. Unfortunately LineageOS has already droppen support for your device, hence you can only use an unofficial custom ROM. https://forum.xda-developers.com/k5-plus/development

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)